# Item RadioButton

Tags: android, sqlite

Si pudieran orientarme como lograr lo siguiente:

Tengo un `ListView` e items  que muestran todos los datos de mi base de datos en SQLite, Coloque un `Radio` `button FIRMA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.firma);` y este se repite en cada Item, es como un formulario en cada item y lo que pretendo es que al clikearlo este inserte X valor a la columna respectiva a los datos mostrados en el item, de tal forma que cuando vuelva a abrir la app el radio `button` ya se encuentre marcado, por lo tanto posteriormente tendría que condicionar si la celda está vacía desmarcado y si no marcado.

Muestro la idea a continuación en una imagen[image: La idea es esta]

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     FIRMA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.firma);

    //////TRASMO SQLITE QUE CONSULTA Y MUESTRA EN UN LIST VIEW /////
    dbcon = new SQLController(this);
    dbcon.open();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Cursor cursor = dbcon.readData();
    String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.IDs, DatabaseHelper.MSG };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ids, R.id.msg };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Hola @Elenasys gracias por contestar,  si salvar todos los elementos marcados y una vez marcado ya no pueda ser posible desmarcarlos, tambien pretendo que al marcar el radio, se envíe los datos por JSON a una B.D en MYSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> salvar todos los elementos marcados y una vez marcado ya no pueda ser
>   posible desmarcarlos, tambien pretendo que al marcar el radio, se
>   envíe los datos por JSON a una B.D en MYSQL

Te comento que para indicar selección de varios elementos en una UI se usan [**checkbox**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html), si fuera seleccionar únicamente un elemento usarias [radiobuttons](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html).

Este seria un ejemplo del adapter usado para tu proposito:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Firmas> {

  private ArrayList<Firmas> FirmasList;

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
    ArrayList<Firmas> FirmasList) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, FirmasList);
   this.FirmasList = new ArrayList<firmas>();
   this.FirmasList.addAll(FirmasList);
  }

  private class ViewHolder {
   TextView nombre;
   CheckBox chk;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

   if (convertView == null) {
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.Firmas_info, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
   holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.chk.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
     public void onClick(View v) {  
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;  
      Firmas Firmas = (Firmas) cb.getTag();  
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
       " is " + cb.isChecked(), 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Firmas.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
     }  
    });  
   } 
   else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   Firmas firmas = FirmasList.get(position);
   holder.nombre.setText(" (" +  Firmas.getNombre() + ")");
   holder.chk.setText(Firmas.getName());
   holder.chk.setChecked(Firmas.isSelected());
   holder.chk.setTag(Firmas);

   return convertView;

  }

 }
```

y este el objeto usado en el adapter:

```
public class Firmas{

 String nombre = null;
 String chkText = null;
 boolean selected = false;

 public Firmas(String nombre, String chkText, boolean selected) {
  super();
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.chkText  = chkText ;
  this.selected = selected;
 }

 public String getNombre() {
  return nombre;
 }
 public void setNombre(String nombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
 }
 public String getChkText() {
  return chkText ;
 }
 public void setchk(String chkText ) {
  this.chkText  = chkText ;
 }

 public boolean isSelected() {
  return selected;
 }
 public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
  this.selected = selected;
 }

}
```

Tienes que agregar un campo donde se guardara el estado de tu checkbox por cada registro, y dentro de

```
   holder.chk.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
```

implementar el guardado a base de datos.

Te recomiendo veas este ejemplo el cual esta explicado completamente y tiene todos los elementos para crear el ejemplo:

**[Android ListView Checkbox Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html)** (inglés)

Answer (score 1):

Bien, lo primero es decirte que por definición cuando usas un `RadioButton` (o un grupo de ellos) es para agrupar items que se excluyen entre sí (solo existe una única selección). Me parece que te vendría mejor para tu caso usar `CheckBox`

Ahora en concreto con tu pregunta, la respuesta es un tanto complicada. Alguna vez lo hice y fué más o menos así:

**Primero**: en tu base de datos tal como indicas, necesitas un *indicador* que será modificado cuando selecciones un item de la lista.

**Segundo**: En este punto supongo que tienes un xml en donde defines los componentes (o formulario) de cada item de la lista.

**Tercero**: Ya teniendo los 2 elementos anteriores, debes tener un Objeto (clase Java) que tenga las columnas de tu tabla (veo que no estas usando un ORM), por ende te tocará diseñar un método que recorra tu cursor y cargue un arreglo de objetos del tipo que estás manejando. Por ejemplo, si tengo una tabla Productos en mi BDD debo tener un objeto Producto en mi modelo y un método como este para pasar de un cursor a mi modelo de objetos, este metodo se debería aplicar por cada iteración que se realiza en el cursor

```
private Producto cursorToProducto(Cursor cursor) {

    Producto p = new Producto();
    p.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    p.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
    p.setUnidades(cursor.getInt(2));
    p.setPrecio(cursor.getDouble(3));
    p.setImporteImpuesto(cursor.getDouble(4));
    p.setImpuestoAplicado(cursor.getDouble(5)); 
    p.setCod_impuesto(cursor.getString(6)); 
    p.setMarcadorTachado(cursor.getInt(8));
    return p;
  }
```

Implementación en el recorrido del `Cursor`:

```
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Producto p = cursorToProducto(cursor);
    //retorno es una lista tipo List<Producto>
    retorno.add(p);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

**Cuarto**: En lugar de `SimpleCursorAdapter` implementé un `Adapter` custom del tipo de objeto que estoy trabajando

```
public class ProductArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Producto> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    ...
}
```

Este punto es extenso y es el más complicado, te recomiendo leer este [post](https://danielme.com/2013/10/09/diseno-android-listview-con-checkbox/) en donde lo explican muy bien.

**Quinto**: Específicamente en él método `getView` de tu `ArrayAdapter` deberás incluir las sentencias para que cuando se active el `CheckBox` se actualice el registro en la base de datos, algo como esto

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
        Producto p = (Producto) cb.getTag();
        p.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
        //evaluar el retorno de cb.isChecked() si es cierto
        //ejecutar la rutina de update en BDD
    }
});
```

De igual manera. allí mismo puedes ejecutar las instrucciones para los casos en que ya el item está seleccionado. Inhabilitar el `CheckBox` por ejemplo.

Luego de todo esto, el propio `ArrayAdapter` deberá mostrarte los datos de forma adecuada, siempre y cuando ejecutes correctamente tus rutinas de actualización en base a los eventos de los `CheckBox`

Espero te ayude.